# How to join tables to get correct result?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables:

Things:

```
+----+---------+--+
| id |  type   |  |
+----+---------+--+
|  1 | issue   |  |
|  2 | issue   |  |
|  3 | issue   |  |
|  4 | issue   |  |
|  5 | issue   |  |
|  6 | bug     |  |
|  7 | bug     |  |
|  8 | bug     |  |
|  9 | bug     |  |
| 10 | bug     |  |
| 11 | project |  |
| 12 | project |  |
+----+---------+--+
```

Links:

```
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
| id | source | destination | link_type |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |           6 | i_b       |
|  2 |      2 |           7 | i_b       |
|  3 |      3 |           8 | i_b       |
|  4 |      1 |          10 | i_p       |
|  5 |      2 |          11 | i_p       |
|  6 |      3 |          10 | i_p       |
|  7 |      4 |          11 | i_p       |
|  8 |      5 |          10 | i_p       |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

I would like to list all things of type issues in the first column and all connected bugs to them in the second column (link_type = i_b). If there is no connected bug there should be `NULL`:

```
+----------+--------+
| issue_id | bug_id |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | 6      |
|        2 | 7      |
|        3 | 8      |
|        4 | NULL   |
|        5 | NULL   |
+----------+--------+
```

I tried to do it with joins, but cannot get rows with issues without bugs connected:

```
select issue.id as issue, bug.id
from things issue
    left join links
        on issue.id = links.source
    join things bug
        on links.destination = bug.id
```

which results:

```
+-------+-----+
| issue | bug |
+-------+-----+
|     1 |   6 |
|     2 |   7 |
|     3 |   8 |
+-------+-----+
```

with missing issues 4 and 5.

Comment: This isn't clear. If you have a source id like 1, of type issue, and there is one row where the destination is a bug and **one more row** with the same source id where the destination is **not** a bug, do you want the second row to be ignored? It seems so, since in your data you don't have just the row (1, 6), you ALSO have the row (1, 10) which should produce the result (1, NULL) in the output. But you don't show it in the output. THEN, what if there are TWO rows with the same issue id as source, and two DIFFERENT bug id's as destination? What if you have both (1, 6) AND (1, 7) in inputs?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore second row (which is link_type = i_p) - I want only link_type = i_b.

Comment: To the second question: if there is (1,6) and (1,7), there should be 2 rows in output. I didin't think about it before.

Comment: As an aside, there should be no `link_type` column in the second table; it is at best redundant (it encodes information already available elsewhere), and at worst it may **contradict** information available elsewhere. If you need it for quick computations, it should be added to a view on the second table (perhaps a materialized view with fast refresh, if needed).

Comment: In the first table, id=10 is a bug, so you should have (5, 10) in the outputs. Why (5, NULL)?

Comment: Also: In your inputs, in table `links` the type of every source is `issue`. Is that a feature of your problem, or is that just poorly chosen test data?

Comment: Link type is not redundant and it was in database before. Things can be connected with all link types.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in my first post :( All link ids from 4 to 8 should have destination 11 or 12 (not 11 or 10)...

Comment: Still, in the output I would like to get (4, NULL).

Comment: Both tables have example data.

Comment: Now I see that my mistake in links table might be not a mistake. We consider only i_b link_type and the issue with ID=4 hasn't that connection, so output should have been also (4, NULL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select issues from `Things` (with `type = 'issue'`). Outer join `Links` that link a bug to an issue (i.e. `link_type = 'i_b'`).

```
select
  t.id as issue_id,
  l.destination as bug_id
from things t
left join links l on l.source = t.id and l.link_type = 'i_b'
where t.type = 'issue';
```

(You could add an outer join to `'bug' Things` records, but you'd gain nothing. Except maybe for some insurance against invalid `Links` entries. The database cannot really guarantee data integrity - e.g. that an `'i_b'` record really contains an issue ID and a bug ID - because you chose a very generic design for some reasons that has this drawback.)

Comment: That is the correct solution! I got the exactly output I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the second join to be a left join:

```
select issue.id as issue, bug.id
from things issue
    left join links
        on issue.id = links.source
    left join things bug
        on links.destination = bug.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got then all types of things in the result in both columns. If I put "where" condition to list only issues in the first column and bugs on the second, I got no nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the source is an 'issue' requires only a semi-join (an `IN` condition, less expensive than a complete join). You also need to differentiate between rows with an issue id and a non-bug destination, depending on what other rows may exist where the destination **is** a bug. This requires more than just joins. I solve that with a call to the analytic function `count()` in a subquery.

```
with things ( id, type ) as (
       select  1, 'issue'   from dual union all
       select  2, 'issue'   from dual union all     
       select  3, 'issue'   from dual union all
       select  4, 'issue'   from dual union all
       select  5, 'issue'   from dual union all
       select  6, 'bug'     from dual union all
       select  7, 'bug'     from dual union all
       select  8, 'bug'     from dual union all
       select  9, 'bug'     from dual union all
       select 10, 'bug'     from dual union all
       select 11, 'project' from dual union all
       select 12, 'project' from dual
     ),
     links(  id, source, destination, link_type ) as (
       select 1, 1,  6, 'i_b' from dual union all
       select 2, 2,  7, 'i_b' from dual union all
       select 3, 3,  8, 'i_b' from dual union all
       select 4, 1, 10, 'i_p' from dual union all
       select 5, 2, 11, 'i_p' from dual union all
       select 6, 3, 10, 'i_p' from dual union all
       select 7, 4, 11, 'i_p' from dual union all
       select 8, 5, 10, 'i_p' from dual
     )
-- end of test data (NOT part of the solution); query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select issue, bug
from ( select l.source as issue,
              case when t.type = 'bug' then l.destination end as bug, 
              count(case when t.type = 'bug' then 1 end) 
                                 over (partition by l.source) as ct
       from   links l inner join things t on l.destination = t.id
       where  l.source in (select id from things where type = 'issue')
     )
where bug is not null or ct = 0
;
```

**Output**:

```
ISSUE BUG
----- ---
    1   6
    1  10
    2   7
    3   8
    3  10
    4
    5  10

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: //edit: as I commented the main post: only i_b link types are considered.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood correctly. 
Please check below query.

```
select issue.id as issue, bug.id from things  
left outer join links
on issue.id = links.destination 
where a.type = 'issue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one join, if we assume (as in your sample data) that all issues are in `links`.  Also, I think you want to check of "bug" in the type column:

```
select l.source as issue, bug.id
from links l left join
     things bug
     on bug.id = l.destination and bug.type = 'bug';
```

If this is assumption is not correct, you can use `issues` with two `left join`s:

```
select l.source as issue, bug.id
from issues i left join
     links l
     on i.id = l.source left join
     things bug
     on bug.id = l.destination and bug.type = 'bug';
```

Comment: First solution is nearly correct, but in the output there is (2, NULL). There shouldnt't be, bacause thing with ID=2 has a connected bug.

Comment: Second solution gives the same result with 6 more rows with both columns NULL.